# Have issue with magento 2 not loading css and js on live site

Tags: magento2, admin, javascript, css, loading

Have this issue all css and js are not loaded on live site.
Tried with terminal to do this.

**php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f**

then **php bin/magento indexer:reindex**

and in the end **php bin/magento cache:flush**

And after all this still have issue with css and js not loading.
I need help bad.

Comment: You do have multi store website?
Also share console error aor any other errors.

Comment: not a multi site here is the link https://industria.rs/

Comment: Do you have multi language?

Comment: I see site is running now.. please close this question now or add answer

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely issue with server configuration, look at .css or .js urls for example:

```
https://industria.rs/pub/static/frontend/Smartweb...
```

It should be something like:

```
https://industria.rs/static/version1644913932/frontend/Smartweb...
```

Check if your root folder is properly configured in server to be [MagentoRootDir]/pub/ and also compare your nginx configuration with [default nginx conf](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/nginx.conf.sample)

Comment: Im not that good with configuration but will try. Could you help and share what file need to be edited

Comment: @AleksandarZubic. sorry to say but your are totally wrong. we can disable "version1644913932" this thing from admin. in his case it could be disabled. issue is something else.